iOS - Restore Previously-Dismissed Live Activity
I'm developing a live activity for my iOS app. I seem to have dismissed it accidentally (I can see the activityState is dismissed) and now I can't get it back. I tried restarting the phone, toggling off/on the live activity app permission, and even deleting the app, but the live activity won't re-appear—whenever I start it, it immediately goes from active to the dismissed state.
How can I tell the system I want to see live activities from my app again?

Well, this makes...no sense to me. But it turned out to be related to an image I was using in the widget. I hadn't checked "Preserve Vector Data" flag, and without it, the widget was never showing. With it checked, the widget showed again.
Trillion dollar company, folks.

heh good one :)   live activity question!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78742542/for-a-live-activity-how-can-i-put-my-widget-bundle-widgetbundle-in-a-target

Apparently if there's anything wrong with the view, it will just dismiss. I had the same behavior when using a Text(timerInterval: ) and accidentally passing in a negative time. No warnings, no errors, took half a day and had to restart because I couldn't figure it out.

To further clarify, it was a Text(timerInterval: Date.now...sleepTimerEnd) and I was accidentally passing in a sleepTimerEnd < Date.now
